# Returning data rows using a date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple PHP function sitting on my server that looks at the database and returns table rows that sit between the dates passed in. The code looks like this

```
if(isset($_GET['startDate'])) {
  $startDateRaw = $_GET['startDate'];
  $startSplit = explode("_", $startDateRaw);
  $startDate = date('d/m/Y', mktime(0,0,0, $startSplit[1], $startSplit[0], $startSplit[2]));
  $endDate = date('d/m/Y');

  if(isset($_GET['endDate']))
  {
    $endDateRaw = $_GET['endDate'];
    $endDateSplit = explode("_", $endDateRaw);
    $endDate = date('d/m/Y', mktime(0,0,0,$endDateSplit[1], $endDateSplit[0], $endDateSplit[2]));
  }
```

It then connects to the database and then runs this query and encodes the result

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM AppointmentList WHERE (DateCreated >= STR_TO_DATE($startDate, '%d%m%Y') AND DateDue <= STR_TO_DATE($endDate, '%d%m%Y'));";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
   while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $posts[] = array('Appointments'=>$post);
   }
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('Appointments'=>$posts));
```

The query is executed, but no data is returned (there is a shed load of data between the date ranges).

The code can be seen running at [appointments code](http://www.all-the-johnsons.co.uk/php/getAppointmentsForDateRange.php?startDate=1_9_2016&endDate=30_9_2016)

I'm guessing something is wrong between the conversion in STR_TO_DATE and the format $startDate and $endDate are in, but can't see what it is.

Comment: Please don't use PHP's long-since deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: Why are you converting it twice? Just convert it to `Y-m-d` format the first time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your dates in your php program look like this: `'12/31/2015'`

If that is the case, you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` like this to get successful conversions to MySQL's internal date format. Notice the `/` characters in the format string.

```
 STR_TO_DATE($startDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
```